# Geo Nodes: generate non-intersecting paths like on a circuit board

Tags: workflow, geometry, geometry-nodes

I want to make a circuit board out of a plane, and it has to be procedural too. I'm looking into a solution that spawns paths from a square, which make seemingly random 45° or 90° turns and yet don't intersect.

[image]

Comment: please add a picture, screenshot of what you like to have. There might be some non-pilots in here....

Comment: There, I added it

Comment: i am not sure whether geometry nodes is "the easiest" solution here. Might be better to use sverchok or animation nodes...

Comment: i know, right? But I just wanna explore the breaking point of geo nodes. This is more like an experiment to see how much can be achieved with geo nodes.

Comment: I guess this is more like an experiment - I agree with you on that, so this question is not really asking for a proper solution to a specific problem. It's more like asking for brainstorming and trying out something...

Comment: I think a more focused, and so valid question would be: How to spawn curves from external dots (dots on edge) of a 2D array of dots, that move outwards, don't intersect and make random 45°/90° turns.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady EXACTLY! You hit the nail RIGHT on the head! Spawning isn't a difficult issue. What really makes my head turn is how to keep them from intersecting each other.

Comment: You need some kind of sequential algorithm I think, and until we have loops in GN it's going to be really hard. But it's coming in one of the future release !